# Why are Radial basis function networks not particularly suitable for extrapolation?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, radial-basis

Assuming you have a regression problem where the test data is quite likely to be outside the range of the training data; hence, the model needs to extrapolate from the training set.

Why are RBF networks not particularly suitable for extrapolation?

Comment: I was thinking because they only apply to a particular area of the input space?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).